# Is there a downside to raising the maximum number of people on a ride?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-2

In RCT1 and RCT2, the Hedge Maze and Spiral Slide allow you to increase the maximum number of people that can be on the ride at once. So a newly built Spiral Slide will allow 2 people on at a time by default, but you can increase the limit to 5.

Is there any reason not to increase the maximum number of people that can be on a ride?

[image: Slide with maximum of 2 people on ride]

Comment: I *think* increasing the amount of people on a ride will increase the chance of it breaking down.

Comment: While I can't speak to RCT1 and RCT2, in OpenRCT2 (which aims to be a fairly accurate reimplementation), increasing the amount of people does not affect breakdowns; that's purely a function of reliability, which is only impacted by lift chain speed, ride age, and inspections.

Comment: It also won't influence the rating of the park? ("*This ride is too crowded*" :)

Answer (score 1):

On rides like these (at this point in time I believe Spiral Slide and the Maze are the only rides with this option) you can allow the option "Unlimited Rides per Admission", which can cause the queue time to increase. Therefore to counter for this, you can increase the number of admissions.

This option allows for the validity of the ride to increase as the park goes on (after a while attendants do get bored of it), so you can milk it for more money as time goes on.

**So, there's no reason to *not* increase it to its maximum, only a reason to not increase it straight away.**

[Source](https://rct.fandom.com/wiki/Spiral_Slide#Other_Information)

As for other rides, such as Rollercoasters, they increase the weight of the cars/trains, which can affect the speed and power of the ride (some might not be able to crest a rise of the track (or overshoot and cause accidents - like with Shuttle Loop). For rides like the boat hire, it doesn't really matter - if anything you can use this to allow more people on the ride at once.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of why you might _not_ want to increase the maximum number of people...

Comment: As I mentioned you would use this option to milk the ride for more money - so the answer is "there's no reason why not - only not immediately"

Answer (score -5):

It would make the ride slower due to the added weight.

Comment: I assume this is referring to roller coasters where each guest in a train adds weight affecting speed and momentum.